Which Passuk goes here: ברוך ה׳ לעולם version
Having davened from a number of Nusach Ashkenaz siddurim over the years, I've noticed that one passuk seems to be inconsistent in the berachah of Baruch Hashem le'Olam/Yiru 'Eineinu.
In some siddurim, the passuk printed is from Tehillim (106:47)

הוֹשִׁיעֵ֨נוּ׀ ה֘' אֱלֹהֵ֗ינוּ וְקַבְּצֵנוּ֮ מִֽן־הַגּ֫וֹיִ֥ם לְהֹדוֹת לְשֵׁ֣ם קָדְשֶׁ֑ךָ לְהִשְׁתַּבֵּ֗חַ בִּתְהִלָּתֶֽךָ

In others, it is Divrei HaYamim (16:35)

הוֹשִׁיעֵ֙נוּ֙ אֱלֹהֵ֣י יִשְׁעֵ֔נוּ וְקַבְּצֵ֥נוּ וְהַצִּילֵ֖נוּ מִן־הַגּוֹיִ֑ם לְהֹדוֹת֙ לְשֵׁ֣ם קׇדְשֶׁ֔ךָ לְהִשְׁתַּבֵּ֖חַ בִּתְהִלָּתֶֽךָ

Why do different siddurim print different pesukim in this berachah? Not just the difference of a word, but of a few words and a sufficiently distinct prosody.
Do any sources address this discrepancy?

Some (incl. Magen Avraham, maybe?) were unhappy with the number of azkarot in the first verse (because it made the total number more than 18 or 19, or whatever they were aiming for), so switched it to the latter verse.
